# passar valor de select com array por ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Preciso de passar a informação de um select array por ajax mas não estou a conseguir.
O meu form:

```
<form method="post" id="form1">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="table-data">
<tr>
<td>   
<select name="sel1[]" id="sel1" onblur="run_sel(this)">
<option value="1">Valor 1</option>
<option value="2">Valor 2</option>
<option value="3">Valor 3</option>
</select>
</td>
<td><span class="tr_clone_add">+</span></td>
<td><span class="tr_clone_del">-</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<div id="sel1_e"></div>
```

O jQuery:

```
<script>
var table = $( '#table-data' )[0]; 
$( table ).delegate( '.tr_clone_add', 'click', function () { 
    var thisRow = $( this ).closest( 'tr' )[0]; 
    $( thisRow ).clone().insertAfter( thisRow ).find( 'input:text' ).val( '0' ); 
}); 

$(table).delegate( '.tr_clone_del', 'click', function () { 
    if($('.tr_clone').length > 1) { 
        var thisRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0]; 
        thisRow.remove(); 
    } 
});

function run_sel(sel) {     
    var text = $("#sel1").val();
        if (text != "") {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: { sel1: text },
            beforeSend: function() { $("#loaderdiv").show(); },
            success: function(data) { $("#loaderdiv").hide(); }
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                $("#sel1_e").html(data);
                $("#form1")[0].form.reset();
            });
        }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Qual o problema que está acontecendo?

Comment: Tem uns erros aqui: `value="1'`... abre com aspas duplas e fecha com simples

Comment: @dvd, corrigido. obrigado.

Comment: Aqui tb: `$("#form1")[0].form.reset();`.. seria `$("#form1")[0].reset();`

Comment: @dvd, na página ajax.php recebe apenas o primeiro valor selecionado se não usar implode, com implode não aparece nada.

Comment: Pelo que entendi vai receber o valor da option selecionada.

Comment: Pelo `name="sel1[]"` entende-se que vc quer enviar um array... mas só tem 1 select... como iria enviar um array se só tem 1 select?

Comment: @dvd, inclui o codigo na pergunta que monta o array, erro meu não ter colocado logo de inicio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialize o formulário e envie pelo `data:`:

```
data: $("#form1").serialize(),
```

O valor de `$_POST['sel1']` no PHP será uma array com o valor de cada `select`. Você pode usar `implode()` para converter em string com os valores separados por vírgula:

```
implode(",", $_POST['sel1']);
```

Agora, há um erro nesta linha:

```
$("#form1")[0].form.reset();
```

O correto seria:

```
$("#form1")[0].reset();
```